# Spring example where values are not hard-coded in XML config files

Tags: java, spring

I am learning Spring and I would just like to ask is there a way to assign values to Bean properties during runtime?
All of the examples that I have tried in the internet and books usually implement hard-coded values in xml files.

 For example a short tutorial found in this website http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-bean-setter-injection-1.html
The User class has getter and setter methods but all of its values are hard-coded at beans.xml. I tried setting values to User's member variables via the setter method in main() but I got alot of errors.
 So am just wondering if this is possible, if it is I would greatly appreciate if you can show short samples or websites that has this tutorial. Thanks in advance.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unexpected failure during bean definition parsing
Offending resource: class path resource [SimpleValues.xml]
Bean 'insertValues'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: <property> element for property 'name' must specify a ref or value
Offending resource: class path resource [SimpleValues.xml]
Bean 'insertValues'
    -> Property 'name'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:579)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:446)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.processBeanDefinition(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
    //More errors
```

this is my xml file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="insertValues" class="com.SimpleValues.SimpleValues">
        <property name="name"/> 

        <property name="age"/>

        <property name="height"/>

    </bean>

</beans>
```

main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        ctx.load("SimpleValues.xml");
        ctx.refresh();

        SimpleValues inject = (SimpleValues) ctx.getBean("insertValues");
        inject.setName("Andres");
        inject.setAge(20);
        inject.setHeight(7);

        System.out.println("Name: "+ inject.getName()+ " Age: "+inject.getAge()+ " Height: "+inject.getHeight());
    }
```

Comment: Post those "lot of errors"?

Comment: hi pangea i updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the errors, you'll see it's complaining (correctly) that your XML is invalid (you're using ill-formed `<property/>` nodes. Assuming you really do have code elsewhere which obtains a reference to `insertValues` and calls the setters, then simply remove the 3 `<property/>` nodes from your XML.

That is, just use:

```
<bean id="insertValues" class="com.SimpleValues.SimpleValues" />
```

That will create your `insertValues` bean and not call any of the setters.

Comment: hi imaginary boy, I updated my post where I added my main java file. I set values by using setters of SimpleValue class. Also I removed the properties as you suggested. Everything is working fine now. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: I also have a quick follow up question on this. By removing the property tag. Spring's operation in this program is just to instantiate the SimpleValues object. In big applications where they use Spring, is this pattern also followed where Spring just manages the objects and leave the assignment of values to other classes or via their setter methods?

Comment: It's probably pretty unusual to do what you're doing. In particular, if you really are just hard coding the values in your code (as opposed to getting them from command line or some other external source) then you're actually creating a worse "hard-coded" scenario than what you seemed to be objecting to. Changing the .xml doesn't require that you recompile your code.

Comment: In my example I hard-coded the values using setter method coz I just wanted to experiment if the values will disappear once Spring destroys the object it created. But referring to my original question, what I wanted to know is how can spring help in getting values from the user during run time. For example getting values from html forms, accepting values from databases via hibernate etc. Are there also methods only available to Spring to do this? or its the same way using setters or passing it through constructors as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are facing is that you must provide a *ref* (i.e. a reference to another Spring bean) or a *value* when working with properties. In your example, since you are referring to primitives (and not other beans), you could get away with something like:

```
<bean id="insertValues" class="com.SimpleValues.SimpleValues">
    <property name="name" value="Andres"/> 
    <property name="age" value="20"/>
    <property name="height" value="7"/>
</bean>
```

By doing this, you can skip the setter methods in the `main` method and get the corresponding values from the `SimpleValues` bean directly after you have fetched it from the application context.

See the [examples](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-some-examples) and read more about [setter based dependency injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-setter-injection) in the Spring reference docs.

Answer (score -1):

In here, while trying to initialize the values dynamically, try to get the values in the set property of the bean class(Using Scanner method), and in the XML file pass default values, that way, the access goes to the setter method and you can initialize the values in there and use those values while getting the values in getter method.